# Memory-efficiently downloading and parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, download

I'm looking for some suggestions for downloading and parsing JSON because i'm getting crash logs from users that tells me they got an OutOfMemoryError.

What I'm using now is the following code:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, Integer.parseInt(connectionTimeOut + "000"));
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(theUrl);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
result = client.execute(request, handler);
return result;
```

with the result I create a json object by doing `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result)` and create my own custom object from this JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would firstly check that the OOME is caused by processing large JSON objects.

If so, perhaps use a JSON library such as GSON in conjunction with Retrofit, which allows you to read objects directly from the input stream, as opposed to reading the entire input stream into a string first.

If even that is too heavy (for instance, if the JSON object nests deeply, buffering the input stream may cause the device to run out of memory), you could consider writing your own GSON TypeAdapter to read specific areas of the input stream.

Comment: it's not that the JSON objects nets to deep, but there can be alot of jsonobjects as data i'm getting returned. But ill try GSON and see how it works.

Comment: As Paul suggested you should try retrofit, it's really easy to set up and will save you a lot of time and effort. Also works really well with RxJava.